# Expires header has values of last year date

Tags: caching, http-headers, webserver, magento2

I am seeing an old expiry date in headers. This is on a Firefox browser for Magento 2 site using nginx with FPC on. Please see below header. Is this something to be worried about?

[image]

Comment: Read on how [expires](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expires) works. There is an important note in the docs: **If there is a Cache-Control header with the `max-age` or `s-maxage` directive in the response, the `Expires` header is ignored.**. And in your case it is. So your **Expires** does nothing!

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. so there is nothing i need to be worried about. Is that correct?

Comment: I wouldn't be worried much, no. Check @BarryPollard answer as well. He's saying the same thing (he has introduced another valid point, that you can only for browser older than ~2008).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it’s intending this asset not to be cached. Notice the cache-control sets `max-age` to 0 and `must-revalidate` and some other directives.

Expiries is only used by older clients that do not understand the cache-control header (which is basically every browser has for the last 10 years) but it doesn’t allow a “do not cache” value so a hack around that is to set an old date to indicate it’s already expired.

So the question for you is: do you want to cache this? If so then yes this is a problem, if not then it is working as intended.

There’s massive performance gains to caching, for when you use the asset again (on a different page, or by coming back to this page) but on the flip side it adds complications if you want to have a new version of the asset.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. These are header details from pagination links of a magento 2 site. I am not sure if paging (like ?p=2) to should be cached. This is might a different question all together. Do you have any advice on this?

Comment: If the list of items are liable to change fairly regularly then probably shouldn't be cached. Or only cached for a very short time (e.g. 5 mins). Really depends on on often they change and whether it's acceptable to show the old content or it must be updated as soon as you can.